# Splicing electric in attic properly

Tags: electrical, ceiling, splicing

I am installing ceiling lights on my attic that has only fiberglass insulation. I needed to splice some cables half way to the fixture box. I just want to verify that I've done so properly.

Here is what I've done: I've spliced the cables with the plastic caps and encased the plastic in [this box](http://www.lowes.com/pd_70940-427-8146_1z10wa6Z1z0xc7b__?productId=1098481&pl=1) (which is a metallic fixture box):

[image]

Then I secured the cables using the clamps in the box, secured the box to the joist and put a lid on the box.

Is this okay? I know some say that one should use a junction box but I had the fixture box with the lid handy so I figured it doesnt make much of a difference but I just want to make sure.

Comment: What you've posted a link to is a form of junction box. Did you ground the box?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That qualifies as a junction box. Provide you did everything else correct, (affixed the box to something a rafter, stud, etc., connected the box itself to the ground wire inside, covered any previously knocked-out knock-outs, etc.) then you're fine.

Comment: And it has a large enough volume.

Comment: When you say "connected the box itself to the ground wire inside", do you mean just to the ground wire in the cable he's spliced into?  Or is it supposed to be grounded separately? (sorry, I'm not an electrician)

Comment: @loneboat:  It means that the ground wires passing through the box should also be securely fastened to the box so as to ground it.

Comment: Where is the box? Is it buried under the insulation or present on a roof rafter and visible?

Comment: Yes, the box must be "accessible".

Answer (score 0):

A box, is a box, is a box. As long as the box is large enough, there's no problem.

Comment: Where "large enough" is defined by code and by what the local Inspectors are willing to pass.